# checking if link is external or not

Tags: actionscript-3

I have another question.

Say i have a link, How can i check if its external or not. What i want to do is the following.
I have 2 strings: `"assets/images/1.jpg" and "http://www.youtube.com/....."`

When the string starts with `"http://"` it should execute function a. Else it should execute function b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (string.indexOf ("http://" > -1) {
    function_a();
}
else {
    function_b();
}
```